# Improving performance on large select lists

Tags: jquery, asp.net, performance, internet-explorer

in my asp.net (c#) web-forms application i have to use very large jquery-dropdown lists (inside a table).
For that i am using the jquery plugin "select2" which has an included search field so i can search for a specific entry ...

On the backend of my ddl i have a sqldatasource which returns >1000 entries. 
In Firefox the rendering of this  tag takes like 2 seconds, but in IE it takes like 6 seconds.

I am already using caching on my datasource but that didnt help much, because i think the bottleneck is the rendering in my case.

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can change your dropdownlist to a Auto Complete box and try to load the result based on the key strokes by the user.

If you are already using Cache then try to cache it in the form of a JSON string and use that to send to the client and use the auto complete at the client.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without knowing exacly what you are doing and what tooling you are using. Hoever you can:

- Use load on demand, when someone scrolls down in your list add extra items.
- Make you list shorter.
- Use a diffrent table control which has better performance.